# Append to file in Android MediaStore

Tags: android, android-storage, android-11

Currently trying to edit a file which I stored in the Downloads collection of the Android 11 / Android R MediaStore API. I edit the file with the following code:

```
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);

                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                try (OutputStream myFile = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(contentUri, "wa")) {
                    myFile.write("XXX Dies ist eine Aenderung XXX".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                }


                catch (Exception e){}
            }
```

After having created it like this, ala with a shorter initial content:

```
        try {
            OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(anUri));
            fos.write("File Hallo".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            fos.close();
        }
```

When the second code is run, I do not get the full message. Instead, Android seems to start to overwrite the file, but only writes as much information as the files original length could take up.

From my reading of the documentation, all I can do is a) make a local copy and b) push that back out to the MediaStore. Can that be? Is there no way to edit the file, which already sits in the file system?

Comment: How are you testing this? IOW, what is your process by which you are determining that your file does not contain the full update?

Comment: I checked the content with the File Explorer pane of Android Studio, and also by opening the file in a local editor!

Comment: If you can create a reproducible sample app, [file a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190602&template=1408010). If you do, and you think of it, pop a link to the issue here!

Comment: Commonsware, as you had ordered - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152333893